# Angular 2: bootstrap-sweetalert not showing popup for success

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular2-routing

Im using npm bootstrap-sweetalert library for displaying the popup for success.

https://github.com/adeptoas/sweet-modal

**admin\src\index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Importing the library here!!-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/sweet-modal/dist/min/jquery.sweet-modal.min.css" />
  <script src="../node_modules/sweet-modal/dist/min/jquery.sweet-modal.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

in my .ts file:

```
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
```

My folder str is :

> Project/admin/node_modules/sweet-modal/dist/the js and css files

But i just get something like where there is no popup and tick animation as shown in library :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery and Angular. You should *really* look for an alternative, Angular friendly.

See https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api